# How to calculate the throughput in TCP?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, throughput, mptcp

I am trying to calculate the throughput for TCP/MPTCP by using the parameter tp->packets_out and also tp->snd_una but they are not accurate.
How does wireshark do it?
Or does anyone know any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of https://github.com/teto/mptcpanalyzer which tries to provide some statistics for MPTCP connections. Current release has many bugs but the upcoming one is much better. Feel free to open issues there if you have any problem.